# flaskとgpioの同時利用ができない(？)スイッチを一回押すと二回処理が出力される。

Tags: flask, gpio

gpioのスイッチを利用したプログラムを作っていたら、「スイッチを一回押すとその処理が二回出力される不具合」に遭遇しました。原因を探るべく削っていった結果、下記のプログラムになりました

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, request, abort
app = Flask(__name__)
BtnPin1 = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BtnPin1, GPIO.IN)

class CallBack:
    def button_pressed1(self, channel):
        print('Callback one')
cb = CallBack()
GPIO.add_event_detect(BtnPin1, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb.button_pressed1, bouncetime=1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
```

このプログラムでも「スイッチを一回押すとその処理が二回出力される不具合」は発生しました。
具体的に言うとスイッチを一回押すと、
Callback one
Callback one
となります。何度やっても瞬間的に二回出力されます。
ハード側が悪いのかと思い、flaskを使わないwhileの無限ループと割り込みのgpioのスイッチのプログラムを作ってみましたが、正常に動きました。

やはりflaskを使用していることが原因になっていると思うのですが、どうすればスイッチ一回で一回の処理を実現できるでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。
因みにLINEbotとgpioのスイッチを利用した物を作ろうとしています。